# How to set up icon dimensions in Leaflet.IconMaterial?

Tags: leaflet, icons, material-design

I'm using the [Leaflet.IconMaterial](https://github.com/ilyankou/Leaflet.IconMaterial) plugin for my leaflet map, but I can't set the dimensions of my icon. How can that be done?

Comment: Next time please avoid asking "Can anyone help me", because you might get "yes" as an answer - https://jdebp.eu/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The dimensions of those icons are hardcoded, [here](https://github.com/ilyankou/Leaflet.IconMaterial/blob/master/dist/leaflet.icon-material.js#L43-L44) for the size of the icon:

```
svg.setAttribute('width', '31');
svg.setAttribute('height', '42');
```

...and then [here](https://github.com/ilyankou/Leaflet.IconMaterial/blob/778e1d9cc8342414a2250684ad5c060c474b93d2/dist/leaflet.icon-material.js#L48-L51) and [here](https://github.com/ilyankou/Leaflet.IconMaterial/blob/778e1d9cc8342414a2250684ad5c060c474b93d2/dist/leaflet.icon-material.js#L53) for the coordinates of the circle and the [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) that together form the "reverse drop" of the icon:

```
backgroundCircle.setAttribute('cx', '15.5');
backgroundCircle.setAttribute('cy', '15');
backgroundCircle.setAttribute('r', '11');
path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M15.6,1c-7.7,0-14,6.3-14,14c0,10.5,14,26,14,26s14-15.5,14-26C29.6,7.3,23.3,1,15.6,1z");
```

Note that the coordinates of the path points as well as the circle fall inside the width and height of the SVG.

Your best bet would be to make a copy of Leaflet.IconMaterial and change those hardcoded values yourself, and/or apply a [scaling transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Transformations) to the circle and the path inside the icon's SVG. Or better yet, make those values configurable via options (then, ideally, document those modifications and merge the code back with the original Leaflet.IconMaterial git repository).

Comment: I've seen this line in the js and I tried to change but the icon don't change the dimensions

Comment: Oooff, you're right, that's the size of the SVG canvas, not the size of the actual path.

Comment: On the other hand, it's usually good to include details of failed attempts when making a question.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry for that. I don't think about it

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez for reply. I have solved with modify the path of svg with this editor [link](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)